# overload of SUBSTRING_INDEX against LEFT in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i have two kinds of code that give an input with for example ',' delimiter and separate items (for instance: input:'1,2,3' output:1 and 2 and 3) , the first is:

```
LABLE: LOOP
    SET a = a + 1;
    IF a <= p_count THEN 
        SET remainder = SUBSTRING_INDEX(input ,',',a);
        SET remainder = SUBSTRING_INDEX(remainder,',',-1);
                SELECT remainder;
        ITERATE LABLE;
    END IF;
    LEAVE LABLE;
END LOOP LABLE;
```

and second is:

```
 SET remainder = input;
 SET delimiter_length = LENGTH(delimiter);
 WHILE LENGTH(remainder) > 0 AND cur_position > 0 DO
         SET cur_position = INSTR(remainder, delimiter);
         IF cur_position = 0 THEN
            SET cur_string = remainder;
         ELSE
            SET cur_string = LEFT(remainder, cur_position - 1);
         END IF;
         SELECT cur_string;
         SET remainder = SUBSTRING(remainder, cur_position + delimiter_length);
 END WHILE;
```

now, i want to know which of them is better in large data, i mean which of them has the lower overload?

Comment: lower overhead in which context: memory of cpu load? What is large data? Can you describe the typical usage scenario of these functions? Did you measure it your self? If not: why not, if yes: what are the outcomes?

Comment: sorry i cant understand what you mean of measure.these functions separate each number without ','

Comment: You have to define: better. Better in which way...